# wxWidgets connect mouse event to a shape object over a wxPaintDC to delete

Tags: c++, events, mouse, wxwidgets

I have a myFrame class, and i am trying to delete Rectangle object but i failed. Something i am doing wrong. OnDoubleClick do not react.

```
class shapes : public wxEvtHandler
...
class Rectangle: public Shape
....
class Circle: public Shape
...
class Line : public Shape
...
-----------------------
class myFrame
...
myViewer* view;
vector<Shape*> shapes;

myFrame::DrawRect(){
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    Rectangle* r=new Rectangle();
    r->setDC(&dc);
    r->drawToDC();
    r->Connect
    (
        wxEVT_LEFT_DCLICK,
        wxMouseEventHandler(myFrame::OnDoubleClick),
        NULL,
        this
    );
    shapes.push_back(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a wxPaintDC outsing an "OnPaint" event handler.
Instead of this, use a wxClientDC or wxWindowDC.

And you'd better pas the wxFrame pointer to the rectangle instead of a wxDC derived class.
Then, the rectangle will get the correct dc when it'll need it.